# How to set IGNITE_H2_DEBUG_CONSOLE with true w？hen Ignite Node starting

Tags: console, h2, ignite

how to set IGNITE_H2_DEBUG_CONSOLE with true？

Using H2 Debug Console
When developing with Ignite sometimes it is useful to check if your tables and indexes look correctly or run some local queries against embedded in node H2 database. For that purpose Ignite has an ability to start H2 Console. To do that you can start a local node with IGNITE_H2_DEBUG_CONSOLE system property or environment variable set to true. The console will be opened in your browser. Probably you will need to click Refresh button on the Console because it can be opened before database objects initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set -DIGNITE_H2_DEBUG_CONSOLE in JVM parameters.

This will start local H2 console. You will be able to find the link to the console in ignite logs.

Regards,
Den

Comment: ignite.bat ../examples/config/example-ignite.xml -J-DIGNITE_H2_DEBUG_CONSOLE=true                                                                                 but        General error: "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException"; SQL statement:
SELECT UPPER(VALUE) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SETTINGS WHERE NAME=? [50000-191] HY000/50000

Answer (score 0):

enter this command in terminal first

"set IGNITE_H2_DEBUG_CONSOLE=true"

then start ignite.bat with your xml file